# Why are more common #include directives not included as default?

Tags: c++, include

I'm thinking particularly of `<iostream>` here. Since it is such a common library that most C++ programs use, why is is not included as default? Other examples are `<string>`, `<fstream>` and `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: Maybe they're common, but you dont need them in ALL of your translation units, don't you?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster just curious as to why they are not default since even if you don't need them, it wouldn't hurt to have them there would it?

Comment: Because there is no universal set of common include directives.

Comment: Probably because it slows compilation down.

Comment: @juanchopanza fair point, but I wasn't thinking of many common ones, just two or three ones that are used a lot of the time, like `<iostream>`

Comment: You might use those a lot of the time, but I don't. So I wouldn't want them included by default.

Comment: @juanchopanza why not? That's basically my question. You may not need them all the time, but it can't hurt, can it?

Comment: In one of our production projects numbering 982 .cpp files, `<iostream>` is included in 5 of those. I must say I am glad it doesn't have to be parsed/processed/loaded from .pch for each of the remaining 977 ones. Or in the other thousands of source files in other projects which make up the complete production suite.

Comment: Because C++ respects the programmer and does not pretend to know what programmer needs or wants.

Comment: @Angew fair enough. if only u had put that in an answer, i'm sure u would have got some rep for it ;)

Comment: Additional headers pollute your namespace, increase compilation time and, possibly, executable size. Besides, I don't use iostream, string and fstream in any of my projects, don't know why you're making such assumptions.

Comment: It does hurt. It introduces an unnecessary (and hidden) dependency, and it affects compilation. Besides the fact that who would decide what this common set of include headers are? Why do you think the set you chose is the most common one? Obviously the most common set is `<funcitonal>`, `<algorithm>` and `<iterator>` and `<vector>`.

Comment: @riv because I use it in all of mine. i'm guessing u use qt or similar...?

Comment: @imulsion It doesn't have to be only because it's replaced by another library. A number cruncher will contain hardly any I/O code, for example.

Comment: such libraries may not be used as frequent as you think by others but ofcourse you can make a header file which includes your favourite  libraries and you can use this header everywhere but it is a bad habit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because there is no common header that is used "a lot of the time".

E.g. `<iostream>` is used only in applications that do a lot of I/O via streams/console, and only if those applications do not use other libraries for the task (ncurses comes to mind for console). And in those applications it's only used in the module(s) that actually *do* the I/O, not in other modules that e.g. do the logic, calculations, persistence to databases etc.

The same pattern of reasoning applies for any other "often used" header. However, you might want to look up precompiled headers, if in your project there are headers that are used in a lot of places. But you might as well want to make your application modular and *not* use API headers in every place.

Answer (score 6):

Common C++ idiom:

> You pay only for what you use.

Comment: i'm guessing that means including things does hurt your program?

Comment: @imulsion including not-needed headers increases compile-time.

Comment: @imulsion no, just slows down compilation/linking

Comment: by how much? is it noticeable?

Comment: @imulsion all is noticeable in C++.

Comment: @imulsion consider a class consisting of only 50 lines total, including some small headers, giving a compilation unit of maybe some hundred lines. Now include soemthing like `<iostream>` that adds some ten thousands of lines. Repeat that for some hundred small classes. You will notice a difference...

Comment: @ArneMertz i see now. Thank you all for your answers :)

Answer (score 2):

It's ironic you picked `<iostream>` as an example:

The C++ Standard Library second edition, p.752

> The header `<iostream>` should be included only if the standard stream objects are to be used. For some implementations, some code is executed at start-up for each translation unit including this header. The code being executed is not that expensive, but it requires loading the corresponding pages of the executable, which might be expensive.

Comment: :Important to notice that "loading the corresponding pages of the executable" happens in any library, not only <iostream> ...

Comment: @Mppl - the issue with `<iostream>` is that it **forces** loading of code pages from every translation unit that includes `<iostream>` during startup in order to ensure that the stream objects get initialized before any possible use. That's on top of whatever issues may be present from merely **using** an outside library.

Answer (score 1):

This things are not included because of performance/executable file size . By providing you the bare minimum things you might need your executable will have the minimum size possible and you will not be linking against libraries you don't use at all.

Including libraries you don't use may in some cases increase the loading time of you program.(This largely depends on you system loading strategy!).
In terms of the performance of the program once loaded there shouldn't be a great difference (if there's any at all!).